# How to know currently open ports on the Windows Firewall?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-firewall

On Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, I can know currently open ports on the Windows Firewall using the following command:

```
netsh firewall show state
```

However, on Windows 7 and Hyper-V Server 2008 R2, when I give that command, it says:

> No ports are currently open on all network interfaces.
>
> IMPORTANT: Command executed successfully.
>   However, "netsh firewall" is deprecated;
>   use "netsh advfirewall firewall" instead.

Apparently there are ports open because services such as NetBIOS NS, Remote Desktop, and Hyper-V remote administration are functioning.

I tried a few 'netsh advfirewall' show commands, but didn't get a way to find out which ports are permit by Windows Firewall.

Knowing the currently open ports, I can be sure that I'm permitting necessary and sufficient traffic to pass in, no more, no less.

Going through the whole set of advanced firewall rules is so tedious and error-prone.

Is there a command on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 to do this efficiently?

Comment: How is it error prone?

Comment: There are so many rules while I'm just interested in the effective ones.

Comment: And that makes it error prone?

Comment: Yeah. Examining dozens of rules in a second is error prone.

Comment: Prone to what errors exactly? Reading them wrong? Why are you trying to read them in one second? Try slowing down a little bit. In addition, in the GUI you can filter the view by the state of the rule, so you could filter it to show only those rules that are enabled.

Comment: Well, I was trying Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 today. It does not have a GUI for Windows Firewall. Anyway, if a command can give us direct result, there's no need to work it out ourselves, right? Especially this feature is available in prior versions, and there is no apparent reason to get rid of it. Perhaps the command just changed a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't get the same results using the same commands is that the Win7 firewall rules can be specific to an individual application, and configured per network type (Private, Domain, Public), protocol, port, etc. Powershell should give you a much better way to query this information and sort it. Here's a quick script I have to dump my configuration, when I need it.

```
Function Get-EnabledRules
{
    Param($profile)
    $rules = (New-Object -comObject HNetCfg.FwPolicy2).rules
    $rules = $rules | where-object {$_.Enabled -eq $true}
    $rules = $rules | where-object {$_.Profiles -bAND $profile}
    $rules
}

$networkListManager = [Activator]::CreateInstance([Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID([Guid]"{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}"))
 $connections = $networkListManager.GetNetworkConnections()
[int[] ] $connTypes = @()
$connTypes = ($connections | % {$_.GetNetwork().GetCategory()})
#$connTypes += 1
Write-Host $connTypes

$connTypes | ForEach-Object {Get-EnabledRules -profile $_ | sort localports,Protocol | format-table -wrap -autosize -property Name, @{Label="Action"; expression={$_.action}}, @{Label="Protocol"; expression={$_.protocol}}, localPorts,applicationname}
```

A lot of this was based off of [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2009/02/18/how-to-manage-the-windows-firewall-settings-with-powershell.aspx) post on MSDN

Comment: what is this -> GetTypeFromCLSID([Guid]"{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}")

Comment: The TechNet post has been archived and can be found at Wayback Machine [TechNet,
James O'Neill's blog - How to manage the Windows firewall settings with PowerShell](https://web.archive.org/web/20141106035740/http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2009/02/18/how-to-manage-the-windows-firewall-settings-with-powershell.aspx)